# Default path SugarCRM in Mac OS

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Can somebody tell me how to find sugarCRM folder in my computer?

I need to go into the Modules folders of SugarCRM. I just installed but I didn't see the root folder.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't select the path for the installation, the default path was:

```
/Applications/sugarcrm-6.5.12/
```

I hope this helps someone else